# How to switch to another language with the tag name div in Google Sign-up page?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I tried to switch the language in Google Sign-up page using Actions I got the "move target out of bounds" error?. Maybe this is not the right way and it is not normal drop-down. We'd have to click (not hover) only then the pop-up kind of list is given to choose the language.

What is the way for us to change it using Selenium?.

URL: https://accounts.google.com/signup?hl=en

Code I've used:

```
d.navigate().to("https://accounts.google.com/signup?hl=en");
d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lang-chooser']/div[1]/div[1]/div[9]/span")).click();
Actions ac=new Actions(d);
    
WebElement eng_uk=d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lang-chooser']/div[1]/div[1]/div[8]/span"));
ac.moveToElement(eng_uk).click().perform();
```

The error I'm getting:

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: move
> target out of bounds

Comment: Hi, Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide a detailed explanation of the problem, along with the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem and your expected output and any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code in Java, it works.

Try-catch blocks can be cleaned out by substituting them with checks for null return of getAttribute() methods.

```
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signup?hl=en");
    
    ArrayList<WebElement> elements = new ArrayList<WebElement>(driver.findElements(By.tagName("div")));
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        
        try {
            
        if(elements.get(i).getAttribute("jsname").equals("wQNmvb")) {
            
            if(elements.get(i).getText().contains("English (United States)")) {
                
                new Actions(driver).moveToElement(elements.get(i)).click().perform();
                
                break;
                
            }
                
            
        }
            
        } catch(Exception e){}
        
        
    }
    
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    elements = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
    
    for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        
        try {
        
        if(elements.get(i).getAttribute("jsname").equals("wQNmvb")) {
        
        if(elements.get(i).getText().contains("Deutsch")) {
            
            JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elements.get(i));
            
            
            
            break;
            
        }
        
        }
        
        } catch(Exception e) {}
        
    }
```